# Dart: dart.exe consumes all memory

Tags: dart

I'm learning Dart and when I run dart project, I'm facing this issue, it make my project unable to run. How can I fix it
[image: this]

Code:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) async {

  String checkNum = oddOrEvenNum(12);
  print('checkNum hahahahah');
}



String oddOrEvenNum(int number) {
  if (number < 10)
    return 'Odd degit';
  else {
    int degitNum = 0;
    do {
      number ~/= 10;
      degitNum++;
      if (number < 10) {
        degitNum++;
      }
    } while (number < 10);

    if (degitNum % 2 == 0)
      return 'Even number with $degitNum';
    else
      return 'Odd number with $degitNum';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have trouble running? How are you running this program? Could it be that instead of restarting your application, you are just starting it multiple times? In short, we need A LOT more details before we are able to help you...

Comment: I updated my code, it's just nearly a new project, I run it but it didn't show anything either on debug console or terminal,I restarted it several times and even create new project but the issue still persists and generate a list dart.exe in task manager like I posted in the issue section. But when I run Flutter app on real device, it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop have a bug which makes your program run forever, without printing anything, since the program will just end up staying inside your while loop.

You should change the following:

```dart
} while (number < 10);
```

Into:

```dart
} while (number > 10);
```

Since `number` are being reduced in size for each loop iteration.